# Gradient of $\ln(\|Ax\|_2^2)$

Tags: matrix-calculus

I want to find gradient of $\ln(\|Ax\|_2^2)$ where $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n} $  and $x \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$.

$\ln(\|Ax\|_2^2)  = \ln((Ax)^{T}Ax) = \ln(x^TA^TAx)$

And I am stuck here. Trying to do it like in one dimensional case would lead to something like $$\frac{1}{x^TA^TAx} * (x^T(A^TA + A^TA))$$

Is it right?

Comment: That is correct, although many would say it's a column vector instead of a row vector.

Comment: Perhaps use the number $2$ rather than repeating $A^T A$ :-). As @greg mentioned, the above is usually called the derivative, the gradient is a element of the ambient (inner product) space. Here that just means the transpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your answer is correct, and it follows from the chain rule. I set the problem up as follows to get the solution:

Let $\phi(\mathbf{x})=A\mathbf{x}$, $\psi(\mathbf{y})=\|y\|^2_2$ and $f(z)=\log(z)$. The expression in the problem is

$g(\mathbf{x})=(f\circ \psi\circ \phi)(\mathbf{x})$

$$ f'(z)=\frac{1}{z}$$
$$\psi'(\mathbf{y})=2\mathbf{y}^\top$$
$$\phi'(\mathbf{x})=A$$

Putting things together under the chain rule

$$
\begin{align}
g'(\mathbf{x})&=f'(\psi(\phi(\mathbf{x}))\,\psi'(\phi(\mathbf{x}))\,\phi'(\mathbf{x})\\
&=\frac{1}{\|A\mathbf{x}\|^2_2}2(A\mathbf{x})^\top A\\
&=\frac{2}{\mathbf{x}^\top A^\top A\mathbf{x}}{\mathbf{x}^\top}A^\top A
\end{align}
$$